# During OnActionExecuting for Web API call - How to map to controller/action class from route string to read action attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I map the incoming route string (e.g. Products/GetProduct) to the Controller/Method that will be called (the ProductsController, GetProduct method)?

My goal is to inspect an instance of the ProductsContoller to find a custom attribute put on the GetProduct method.

I know how to inspect the class once I know which which class/method I'm dealing with.

I had considered just splitting the string, so you'd end up with "Products", and "GetProducts", then I can look for a ProductsController, and within that, a method called GetProducts.

This might work, but seems like there should be a better solution.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why not make the attribute you're looking for an action filter, instead of checking for the attribute from another filter?

Comment: My goal here is to enforce role based security. My concern with your suggestion is that it relies on the developer to remember to properly tag a method. This approach would allow me to use a central method and map to actions in my own security model. I'm open to other ideas, this just seemed like the best way to consolidate and enforce the constraints.

Comment: To add, it's a big project, and we're still a while away from having enough of a unit test framework to check for this at build time.

Comment: You can theoretically create a global filter,or something more advanced would be to implement your own FilterProvider, and it will provide the filter according to some criterion for returning the filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the actual controller instance and attributes on the action using:

```
public class Somefilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller;
            var someFilterattributes = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<Somefilter>()
            var otherAttributes = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<Other>()
        }
    }
```

Where Other is some other filter on the action.

Comment: This is the best answer any one person has given any other person in the history of mankind.

Comment: I tend to agree with you @BenjaminGruenbaum. I weep at the poetic beauty.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the controller name by using the following code inside your **OnActionExecuting** method

```
var controller = actionContext.Request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"];
```

Comment: Not working with WEB API. This is used in ASP.NET MVC. In WEB API actionContext is a HttpActionContext type. In ASP.NET MVC actionContext is a ActionExecutingContext type.

Answer (score 0):

In Web API to get controller name and action:

```
Public Class MyClassActionFilter
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute

    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuted(contexto As HttpActionExecutedContext)
        contexto.Request.Properties.Item("MS_HttpRouteData").Values("controller")
        contexto.Request.Properties.Item("MS_HttpRouteData").Values("action")
    End Sub

    Public Sub New

    End Sub

End Class
```

In **WebApiConfig.vb** add a global filter so you do not need to add the tag in the header of all methods

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(New MyClassActionFilter())
```